# Xls sheet (or XML) to formatted doc

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, xml

I have an excel sheet with four columns (Name, Address, Country, Description) with about 300 rows. I want to create a word document with this info, having each field in different format, i.e.

```
Name (Times New Roman Bold, 16 pt)
Address (Arial, 12 pt)
Country (Arial Bold, 14 pt)
Description (Palatino Linotype, 10 pt)
```

for every record, one after another.

If possible, I would prefer the four entries of the record to have different style (in order to be able to change the style of an entry of every record)
The same info exists in XML format, if that helps more.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate the use of Word's mailmerge feature.

This allows you to specify an exact template for importing and merging tabular data.

Comment: Not enough detail; could as well be a comment.

Comment: It is rather short I'll admit but none the less, it contains the full answer. A simple mailmerge will do exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Maybe some steps or screenshots for those unfamiliar with the feature... Just seems quite terse although I agree with your solution.